# How to get an Angular 10 application working in IE 8?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-8, polyfills

We are working on an Angular 10 application and some users are still using IE 8.

I was wondering if it's possible to get our application working in IE 8 ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support, Angular only support IE11. I'm not sure if there are polyfils that can make it work IE8. IE8 comes with Windows XP, which is not supported anymore by MS

Answer (score 1):

Angular 10 does have conditional support of IE8, just enable pollyfills and some statements in browserlist file. For support, you can reference. https://v10.angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: Thanks for your response, but IE 8 is not listed in the support page :   https://v10.angular.io/guide/browser-support